# What is the "raw HTTP header"? What is the difference between "HTTP header" and "raw HTTP header"?

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-headers, httpresponse

In Zend Framework in Response Class there are two different arrays for storing headers: `_headers[]` and `_headersRaw[]`. And there are appropriate methods for setting each one:

`setHeader(), getHeaders(), clearHeader()` and

`setRawHeader(), getRawHeaders(), clearRawHeaders()`.

What is the reason to have "header" and "raw header"? Is there some special kind of usage in practice for each of these headers?

Comment: Is there no information in the user guide about this?  (Normally I'd just say read the manual, but my experience of the Zend manual is that it's far from comprehensive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using setHeader you set key vale pair without worrying about there formatting e.g

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type','json');
```

while in case of setRawHeader() you put the whole/full header as it is with  proper formating

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late here...

Raw means that the header is not URL-encoded, whereas if the word "raw" is omitted, the header is encoded. For example:

```
$header = 'http://www.mywebsite.com?q=string'; // this is raw, no encoding

echo $header; // no encoding so output is -> http://www.mywebsite.com?q=mystring

echo rawurlencode($header); // URL-encoded so output is -> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%3Fq%3Dstring
```

The special characters  : / ? = have been URL-encoded as

%3A
%2F
%3F
%3D

respectively.