# What does actually mean by the term 'Raw HTTP header' exclusively in PHP?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, webserver, response-headers

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

While reading the PHP manual page on `header()` function I come across the below line describing what the `header()` function does in PHP

**header — Send a raw HTTP header**

**header() is used to send a raw HTTP header.**

I understand the meaning of **HTTP header** and by using `header()` function one can send various type of information from the server to the browser in the form of response headers.

I also know that when the requested page is sent to the browser few default headers are implicitly sent i.e. without using `header()` function in code.

So, my question is what actually mean by the term **'Raw HTTP header'**?

I've nowhere else seen this term 'Raw HTTP header' except the PHP manual page for `header()` function. So, why PHP is exclusively using this unfamiliar term instead of using the term **HTTP Headers**?

Is the **'Raw HTTP header'** different in any sense from **HTTP Header**?

**Note : Please, don't mark my question duplicate. I have seen [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207070/what-is-the-raw-http-header-what-is-the-difference-between-http-header-and) and its answers but they are still not clearing the doubt I have. The answers it has are also specific to Zend Framework and not to plain PHP.**